# SNMP sysObjectID not translated when using Python3 easysnmp module

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, easysnmp

When I query SNMP `sysObjectID` using `easysnmp` module, then returned value is in numerical notation:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from easysnmp import Session
>>> session = Session(hostname="r1", community='public', version=2)
>>> session.get('sysObjectID.0')
<SNMPVariable value='.1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.1.1.2.21' (oid='sysObjectID', oid_index='0', snmp_type='OBJECTID')>
>>>
```

However, this does not seem to be because `easysnmp` is not able to find the correct MIB file. When I put the commands above into a file and execute it with `strace`, then correct MIB is accessed:

```
$ strace 2>&1 -f -e open python3 snmp_test.py | grep mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt
open("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/JuniperMibs_from_Juniper/mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
open("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/JuniperMibs_from_Juniper/mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/JuniperMibs_from_Juniper/mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
$
```

I can double-check this using `snmpget`:

```
$ snmpget -v 2c -c public r1 sysObjectID.0 
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: JUNIPER-CHASSIS-DEFINES-MIB::jnxProductNameMX960
$ strace 2>&1 -f -e open snmpget -v 2c -c public r1 sysObjectID.0 | grep mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt
open("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/JuniperMibs_from_Juniper/mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
open("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/JuniperMibs_from_Juniper/mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/JuniperMibs_from_Juniper/mib-jnx-chas-defines.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
$
```

Still, just to be sure, I set the `os.environ['MIBDIRS']`, `os.environ['MIBS']` and `os.environ['PREFIX']` to same values as I see when I execute the `snmpget -Dinit_mib -m ALL -v 2c -c public r1 sysObjectID.0` command, but this does not help either.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the value at the OID `sysObjectID.0` is just being treated as a value.  It looks like the `use_sprint_value` option enables the extra formatting on the return value:

```
>>> session = Session(hostname="abc", community='public', version=2, use_long_names=True, use_sprint_value=True)
>>> session.get('sysObjectID.0')
<SNMPVariable value='.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.2435.2.3.9.1' (oid='.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysObjectID', oid_index='0', snmp_type='OBJECTID')>
```

Clearly the `use_long_names` option is also helpful to show the expanded name, though I don't have all the MIBs required to decode this example.